# LibSVM in Java and Python gives different output.

Tags: java, python, processing, svm, libsvm

I've been using the high-level python script svmutil.py to generate a svm-model.

But actually, I need to run my SVM in Java. Training a model with the same dataset ( 3000 entries with 18 features and 5 classes) gives me a different amount of nSVs.

```
>>> from svmutil import *
>>> y,x = svm_read_problem('train.txt')
>>> m = svm_train(y[:3000],x[:3000], '-t 2 -s 0')
*
optimization finished, #iter = 67
nu = 0.105257
obj = -89.960869, rho = -0.027008
nSV = 128, nBSV = 126
***
[a couple of more iters here... ]
***
optimization finished, #iter = 19
nu = 0.016800
obj = -10.178571, rho = -0.078282
nSV = 22, nBSV = 19
Total nSV = 430
```

As you can see, the total amount of nSVs is 430.

My Java implementation looks like this ( I guess I've to mention that I'll run this in processing):

```
import libsvm.*;

double[][] train = new double[3000][];  // 3000 entries in training file
double[][] test = new double[952][];    // 952 entries in testing file

Table t; //generated data is saved in a csv in the form of a processing-table
int classes = 5;
svm_model m; 

private svm_model svmTrain() {
    svm_problem prob = new svm_problem();
    int dataCount = train.length;
    prob.y = new double[dataCount];
    prob.l = dataCount;
    prob.x = new svm_node[dataCount][];     

    for (int i = 0; i < dataCount; i++){            
        double[] features = train[i];
        prob.x[i] = new svm_node[features.length-1];
        for (int j = 1; j < features.length; j++){
            svm_node node = new svm_node();
            node.index = j;
            node.value = features[j];
            prob.x[i][j-1] = node;
        }           
        prob.y[i] = features[0];
    }               

    svm_parameter param = new svm_parameter();
    param.probability = 1;
    param.gamma = 0.5;
    param.nu = 0.5;
    param.C = 1;
    param.svm_type = svm_parameter.C_SVC;
    param.kernel_type = svm_parameter.RBF;       
    param.cache_size = 10000;
    param.eps = 0.1;      

    svm_model model = svm.svm_train(prob, param);

    return model;
}

public double evaluate(double[] features, svm_model model) 
{
    svm_node[] nodes = new svm_node[features.length-1];
    for (int i = 1; i < features.length; i++)
    {
        svm_node node = new svm_node();
        node.index = i;
        node.value = features[i];
        nodes[i-1] = node;
    }

    int totalClasses = classes;       
    int[] labels = new int[totalClasses];
    svm.svm_get_labels(model,labels);

    double[] prob_estimates = new double[totalClasses];

    double v = svm.svm_predict_probability(model, nodes, prob_estimates);

    for (int i = 0; i < totalClasses; i++){
        System.out.print("(" + labels[i] + ":" + prob_estimates[i] + ")");
    }
    System.out.println("(Actual:" + features[0] + " Prediction:" + v + ")");                
    return v;
}

void setup(){

int q = 0;
t = loadTable("train.csv", "header");
println(t.getRowCount() + " total rows in table");

 for( TableRow row : t.rows()){
   double[] vals = new double[19]; // 18 features + classID
  for( int p = 0; p< 19; p++){   
   vals[p] = row.getFloat(p);
  }
  train[q] = vals;
  q++; 
 }

 m = svmTrain();
 q = 0;


t = loadTable("test.csv", "header");
println(t.getRowCount() + " total rows in table");

 for( TableRow row : t.rows()){
   double[] vals = new double[18];
  for( int p = 0; p< 18; p++){

   vals[p] = row.getFloat(p);
  Float k = row.getFloat(p); 
  }
  test[q] = vals;
  q++; 
 }    

  double b = evaluate(test[111],  m); 
}
```

So actually, this processing sketch runs without any exceptions, but my output is something like this:

```
optimization finished, #iter = 11
nu = 0.005126779895638029
obj = -2.974715882922519, rho = -0.24619879130684083
nSV = 13, nBSV = 2
Total nSV = 154
952 total rows in table
(0:0.012058316041050699)(1:0.004177821114087953)(2:0.0010059539653873603)(3:0.9816075047230208)(4:0.0011504041564533865)(Actual:0.0 Prediction:3.0)
3.0
```

So basically, with the same dataset, I get a different amount of nSV, and as you can see in the outout of the processing sketch, the predicting function says the value nr 111 is in the class 3, but actually it's in class 0. 
( The python program says SVM can be 97% accurate with this testing and training datasets)

Comment: i solved this problem. I forgot that I've been normalizing the dataset in my processing code whilst collecting in a different way as given to the svm.